# How to print specific data attribute in JSON response object

Tags: javascript, api, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

How to print specific data attribute in JSON response

I get respose like this.

```js
ionViewDidLoad() {
  
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SonglistPage');
    this.eid = this.backendprovider.getEventID();
    console.log('eventID');
    console.log(this.eid);
    this.backendprovider.sendEventID(this.eid).subscribe((songs) => {
      this.songslist = songs;
      
    });

  }
```

I want to print the title of songs object. please help me. Thanks

This is what I tried. But it prints all the object data

```js
 const myObjStr = JSON.stringify(songs);
 console.log(myObjStr);
```

Print Output:

```css
[{"id":{"timestamp":1518586352,"machineIdentifier":3380871,"processIdentifier":5056,"counter":16748217,"time":1518586352000,"date":1518586352000,"timeSecond":1518586352},"songId":1,"title":"Somebody's Me","artist":"Enrique Iglesias","genre":"Jazz"}]
```

Comment: I think you need **JavaScript** tag instead of **java**

Comment: something like `songs[i].title` should do it

Answer (score 0):

use [`map` finction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const songTitles = songs.map(a=>a.title);
console.log(JSON.stringify(songTitles));
```

Answer (score 0):

`songs` variable is an array. You need to iterate the array to get song titles.

```js
ionViewDidLoad() {
  
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SonglistPage');
    this.eid = this.backendprovider.getEventID();
    console.log('eventID');
    console.log(this.eid);
    this.backendprovider.sendEventID(this.eid).subscribe((songs) => {
      this.songslist = songs;
      songs.forEach((song) => {
        console.log(song.title);
      });
    });

  }
```

[Foreach documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

If you use ajax and jQuery to get the response then you can do something like this:

```
$.ajax(function() {
    url:'your endpoint url',
    data: function(d){
        //your data
    }
    success: function(response){
        var songTittle = response['title'];
        console.log(songTittle);//should print Somebody's Me
    }
    error: function(response) {
        //error callback
    }
});
```

But generally speaking, something like this `response['tittle']` should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

it's array result you can print it using *ngFor

```
<div *ngFor = "let song of songslist">
{{song.title}}
</div>
```